# Java ArrayList, Finding Duplicates, in a section of a String

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

I'm looking for some guidance on how to find duplicate entries in a `arrayList` that is populated from a .txt file line by line.

The .txt file lines are as follows:

```
9700874,6187,13-MAR-12,5503.78 ,5503.78 ,99950,4657,0045,4426920621,111000012,YS,9700874,

7531245,58195,13-MAR-12,5464.55 ,5464.55 ,99950,4661,0023,0041800591,275071288,S,7531245,

9319794,53402,13-MAR-12,5461.01 ,5461.01 ,741828,7098,0025,592245,082900911,S,7543539,


A      ,  B ,   C     ,  D     ,   E    ,  F  ,  G , H  ,   I      ,  J      ,K,   L    ,
```

I want my program to read in the file, line by line, and send the current line to another method. Before this, I would like to check to make sure I do not have a line similar in the .txt file. Lines are compared only on fields `A, D and F` for similarities.

I don't have much but here is my code anyhow, grabbing line by line.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    currentline = line;

    //check if currentline(sec A D F) have been proccessed already, if yes skip line,
    //if no send to method 

    proccess(currentline);

    list.add(line);

}
String[] fileLines = list.toArray(new String[0]);
br.close();
```

Comment: you should create a data structure that can store each item of each line in a logical way

Comment: I really didnt understand what you want, but if you want to check if A,D and F are not duplicate a flag could be helpful

Comment: This looks like homework. It's ok asking about homework but your question is too generic and does not show enough research and design effort. It's also not very well specified. Please come back when you have code that you think should work but doesn't.

Comment: it is not clear at all what you are asking? b4 is before ?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a `HashSet<String>` with the value as combination of section A, D & F.

For each line, compute section A+D+F, see whether it exists in the Set, if not - process it and add to set, if yes - ignore it